# Override Import's takeover of Collection?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a new Collection -

```
Dim theSet as New Collection
```

but, I am using the Textsharp PDF creator in my project -

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
```

and Textsharp apparently creates it's own "collection" Namespace, removing the VB.NET one.

Is there a way to override this and use the VB.NET Collection statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much you can do about a library polluting the namespace with common words like that.  It has a Java background and counted on a case-sensitive language.  You'll have to help the compiler by being explicit that you meant to use the VB.NET Collection class and not the iTextSharp.pdf.text.collection namespace.  Either type out of the full class name to disambiguate:

```
   Dim theSet as New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection
```

Or add an alias:

```
Imports VBCollection = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection
...

   Dim theSet as New VBCollection
```

That same aliasing trick works on the library as well:

```
Imports Pdf = iTextSharp.text.pdf
```

And you'll have to prefix `Pdf.` whenever you want to reference a type from that namespace.